# Add inner query column values in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

**I have many tables from which i am getting data** i fetched data correct but only for **collected amount**.

But now i want to get total remaining amount and total outstanding amount region wise.

1. **Be clear that total Outstanding amount is in recovery table**
2. **Collected Amount is in complain action table**.

My requirement is that, i have to show individual collected amount in different day slabs and show total collected, total remaining and total outstanding amount region wise:

Here is Image how i want to show result:

[image]

**Query for fetching bellow data**

```
select sum(y.salab1) salab1,sum(y.salab2) salab2,sum(y.salab3) 
salab3,sum(y.salab4) salab4,sum(y.salab5) salab5,sum(y.salab6) 
salab6,y.regionName,y.zonName from (
select
(CASE
 WHEN (CEIL((DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), rcv.`AGING_DATE`) /15)) = 1 ) THEN  
sum( IFNULL(cpa.`COLLECTED_AMOUNT`, 0) )
ELSE 0
  END) as salab1,
 (CASE
  WHEN (CEIL((DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), rcv.`AGING_DATE`) /15)) = 2 ) 
THEN  sum(IFNULL(cpa.`COLLECTED_AMOUNT`, 0) )
  ELSE 0 
 END) as salab2,
 (CASE
 WHEN (CEIL((DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), rcv.`AGING_DATE`) /15)) = 3 ) THEN  
sum(IFNULL(cpa.`COLLECTED_AMOUNT`, 0) )
  ELSE 0 
 END) as salab3,
 (CASE
  WHEN (CEIL((DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), rcv.`AGING_DATE`) /15)) = 4 ) 
 THEN  sum(IFNULL(cpa.`COLLECTED_AMOUNT`, 0) )
  ELSE 0
 END) as salab4,
 (CASE
 WHEN (CEIL((DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), rcv.`AGING_DATE`) /15)) = 5 ) THEN  
sum(IFNULL(cpa.`COLLECTED_AMOUNT`, 0) )
  ELSE 0
END) as salab5,
  (CASE
  WHEN (CEIL((DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), rcv.`AGING_DATE`) /15)) >5  ) 
THEN  sum( IFNULL(cpa.`COLLECTED_AMOUNT`, 0) )
  ELSE 0
 END) as salab6,

CEIL((DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), rcv.`AGING_DATE`) /15)) as slab
,   rgn.`NAME` as regionName, zn.`NAME` as zonName,rcv.AMOUNT
 from `recovery` rcv
 join complain cmp on cmp.`CODE` = rcv.`COMPLAINT_ID`
 join customerprofile cp on cp.`REG_CODE` = cmp.`CUST_REG_NO`
 join marketofficer mo on mo.`MO_ID` = rcv.`RO_ID`
 LEFT OUTER join complain_actions cpa on cpa.`COMPLAIN_CODE` = cmp.`CODE`
 join market mrkt on mrkt.`ID` = cp.`MARKET_ID`
 join area ar on ar.`ID` = mrkt.`AREA_ID`
 join city cty on cty.`ID` = ar.`CITY_ID`
 join region rgn on rgn.`ID` = cty.`REGION_ID`
 join `zone` zn on zn.`ID` = rgn.`ZONE_ID`
 group by zonName,regionName,slab) y group by y.zonName,y.regionName
```

**This query is fetching collected amount region and zone wise** but i want all

1. collected amount in days
2. Total collected amount
3. Total remaining amount
4. Total outstanding amount

Thanks.